# Can I keep my bank account and SSN after giving up permanent resident status?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, social-security, permanent-resident

If I were to abandon my permanent resident status in US, will I be able to keep and use my Wells Fargo bank account?

Also what happens to my Social Security number?

Comment: @PeterK. you should probably write that as an answer

Comment: @littleadv: Done!

Answer (score 3):

Your SSN is yours for life. Provided you have an SSN or an ITIN (i.e. something to ID you to the IRS), Wells Fargo won't give a fig about your immigration status.